# What does Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint mean?

Tags: unity, c#

Is that the same as changing a Canvas in the editor to World Space mode and then drag a Camera ?

[image: Is this the same as Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint ?]

Answer (score 3):

[This is covered by the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html):

> **Declaration**
>
> `public Vector3 WorldToScreenPoint(Vector3 position);`
>
> **Description**
>
> Transforms position from world space into screen space.
>
> Screenspace is defined in pixels. The bottom-left of the screen is (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight). The z position is in world units from the camera.

So this is a math function that converts a position vector from one coordinate space to another.

You give it the coordinates of a point in your game's world space (like the `transform.position` of an object in your scene), and it returns to you the coordinates of the pixel on the screen where that point would be displayed, given the camera's current view settings.

This has nothing to do with canvas components per se, or what camera they use for their pointer interaction events.

Please be sure to consult the docs first when in doubt — they explain a lot of these basics faster than waiting for an answer here.

Comment: I'm asking because I want to position a UI text above any object either my player or just a simple cube. I'm using in the canvas in the editor the render mode world space and it's working fine. I wonder what is the best way or what's better to use the small script with the Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint like she is doing in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bvDmqqMXcA or like I did with the world space ?

Comment: Sounds like you meant to ask "How do I position a canvas object above a scene object" as your post. Always ask about the problem you want to solve, not your guess at a potential solution. If you use a worldspace canvas you don't need this function: you can position your canvas itself in yor world above your object. You could use this for a screenspace overlay or screenspace camera canvas, you just have to remember that the coordinate system inside your canvas is not the same as pixels on screen — your canvas settings/scaling change it. You can post a new question if you need help with this.